# Using Beautifulsoup to scrape tags from website but skip / ignore some others

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using the following code to scrape the  tags amongst others:

```
for content in soup.find_all():
  try:        
        link = content.find('enclosure')
        link = link.get('url')
        print "\n\nLink: ", link

        title = content.find('title')
        #<item><guid isPermaLink="false"> == is causing doubling of first episode
        #title = content.find('title')
        title = title.get_text()
```

It scrapes the URLs fine but also the following titles which are correct, but obviously picks up the two first ones as instructed. How do I ignore those and start at the title for the episodes (Ep 116)?

(The site I'm scraping is http://feeds.thisiscriminal.com/CriminalShow)

```
<channel>
  <title>Criminal</title>
  <link>http://thisiscriminal.com/</link>
  </description>
    <image>
    <url>https://f.prxu.org/criminal/images/....png</url>
      <title>Criminal</title>
      <link>http://thisiscriminal.com/</link>
      <title>Episode 116</title>
      <link>http://feeds.thisiscriminal.com/~r/...</link>
  <description>
```

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Link does not work.

Comment: Do you want just <title>Episode 116</title>
      <link>http://feeds.thisiscriminal.com/~r/...</link>  ?

Comment: @QHarr Have updated link thanks. Yeah, just the Ep 116 title and then 115, etc. It'st just picking up the first two erroneously because they are also surrounded with <title> tags too

Comment: So, do you want just the link following the title episode? e.g. http://feeds.thisiscriminal.com/~r/..  or the link before? Or all links?

Comment: @QHarr All links starting the numbered episodes thanks. The first two seem to be just website header <titles> not individual episode titles, so there's no .mp3 associated with them link episode 116 and beyond

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like as follows?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('http://feeds.thisiscriminal.com/CriminalShow')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

for item in soup.select('item'):
    print(item.select_one('title').text)
    print([i.get('href', i.text) for i in item.select('[href], link') if i.get('href', i.text) !=''])
```

Comment: That looks good thanks, only thing is I'm not sure how I'd add it to the existing code? e.g. the get_playable_podcast section: https://github.com/leopheard/thisiscriminal/blob/master/resources/lib/thisiscriminal.py

Comment: That might need to be a new question where you include the existing code?